# How to perform $group and $lookup aggregations together

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here I have two collections.

I want to  get publishers details in an array by performing `$group` aggregation or any other method.

**Books**

```json
[
   {
      "_id":8751,
      "title":"The Banquet",
      "author":"AB",
      "copies":2,
      "publisher":[
         1,
         2
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":8752,
      "title":"Divine Comedy",
      "author":"Dante",
      "copies":1,
      "publisher":[
         3,
         1
      ]
   }
]
```

**Publisher**

```json
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"p 1"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"p 2"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"p 3"
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "name":"p 4"
   }
]
```

I have tried with the following query but the result not the expected one.

```js
    db.books.aggregate([
      {
        "$unwind": "$publisher"
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": "$publisher",
          
        }
      },
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "publisher",
          "localField": "_id",
          "foreignField": "id",
          "as": "publishers"
        }
      }
    ])
```

**Expected Output**

```json
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"p 1"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"p 2"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"p 3"
   }
]
```

How to  get publishers list of books in array

Comment: what do you mean publishers list of books in array? in the expected output there is no array.  You can join an array field with a single field, they will match if array contains that element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this aggregation query:

- Frist `$lookup` using the `publisher` array. Yes, you can use an array to join values.
- Then `$unwind` the array returned by `$lookup`.
- And `$group` by `id` to remove duplicates catching `$first` value for the name.
- Then, (optional) use `$project` to output `id` instead of `_id`.
- And (optional) `$sort` by `id`.

```
db.Books.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Publisher",
      "localField": "publisher",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "as": "publishers"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$publishers"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$publishers.id",
      "publisher": {
        "$first": "$publishers.name"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "id": "$_id",
      "publisher": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "id": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NnG289Of1oj)

Note that the output whithout "optional" stages is something like this

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "publisher": "p 1"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "publisher": "p 3"
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "publisher": "p 2"
  }
]
```

And with the all stages of the query:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "publisher": "p 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "publisher": "p 2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "publisher": "p 3"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you want to replace numbers from `publisher` array with documents from the publisher collection. You can simply do it with `$lookup` aggregation pipeline:

```
db.books.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "publisher",
      "localField": "publisher",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "as": "publishers"
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DpXkhTJycPu)